# How to use winapi ReadProcessMemory with vector to read buffer from another process?

Tags: c++, winapi, readprocessmemory

```cpp
std::byte *ReadBytes(PVOID address, SIZE_T length)
{
    std::byte *buffer = new std::byte[length];
    std::cout << "length" << sizeof(buffer) << std::endl;

    ReadProcessMemory(this->processHandle, address, buffer, length, NULL);

    return buffer;
};
```

I'm trying to read memory regions of a process into std::byte array, but with code above, I can't get the length of buffer outside, so I want to change the type of buffer to `std::vector<std::byte>` or use some other methods. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C++11, [`std::vector::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) will provide a pointer to the backing array. If you're using older tools without support for C++ 11, `&buffer[0]` probably works, I've never seen it *not* work, but is not guaranteed by the Standard.

Looking at the code again, if you've got `std::byte`, C++11 support is not an issue.

So...

```
std::vector<std::byte> ReadBytes(PVOID address, SIZE_T length)
{
    std::vector<std::byte> buffer(length);
    std::cout << "length" << buffer.size() << std::endl;

    ReadProcessMemory(this->processHandle, address, buffer.data(), length, NULL);

    return buffer;
};
```

Comment: It works, thank you! And then how to convert part of the buffer to the type I want, like reading buffer[3:11] as unsigned long?

Comment: You need to worry about [strict aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Strict_aliasing) if you're going to interpret portions of an array of bytes as anything but an array of bytes. The safest thing to do is `memcpy` the data out into an array of the appropriate type. `memcpy(&buffer[3], mylongarr, sizeof(mylongarr));`. Only convert with a cast if you have iron-clad guarantees about the alignment

Comment: "*I've never seen it not work, but is not guaranteed by the Standard*" - yes, it is. `std::vector` has always been defined as a contiguous buffer, and `operator[]` returns a reference to its elements, so `&buffer[0]` and `buffer.data()` have always been the same pointer, even in older versions that don't have `data()`

Comment: Even safer: [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast), at least once C++20 is here.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Agree 100%, but I think the reason it's not explicitly called-out out as legal is `vector<bool>` and the possibility of similar proxy-returning specializations.